# HTTP/1.1 204 No Content

Tags: curl, influxdb

I am using the below curl command to push the data to InfluxDB. But, it throws below exception.

My curl command:

```
measurement="download_speed,component=java_jdk,landscape=aws duration=10,status=100"
echo "$measurement" >/tmp/curl.input
curl -k -m 30 -i -XPOST $url/write?db=<database_name> -u ${username}:${password} --data-binary @/tmp/curl.input
```

MY Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.13.8
Date: Mon, 19 Mar 2018 08:39:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Request-Id: 057a880f-2b51-22e8-9r45-000000000000
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.4.2
X-Request-Id: 057a880f-2b51-22e8-9r45-000000000000
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: According to the docs returns 204 as a success code.

Comment: ya.. but i don't see any data written @ influxdb..! :(

Comment: got it solved by adding precision time in seconds.